# I’m gonna get drunk with this

Tags: visual, rebus

[image]

[image]

[image]

My first Riley rebus, and just general rebus. Hope you enjoy!

Comment: One of your pictures is copyright

Comment: Is it? Oh sorry, I didn’t know.

Comment: This should solve it

Comment: Dat scarecrow... DVL2 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you a

> Pellicle?

Explanation:

Prefix

> The picture is a **pell**; a training dummy used by knights in the Middle Ages

Infix

> The picture is of a girl **lic**king a Popsicle

Suffix

> The picture looks like its a fuse of some sorts. Looks sort of like a **CLE** type fuse.

Title

> **Pellicle** is a byproduct of beer brewing. Beer can be used to get **drunk**.

Comment: Correct! Well done!